# Online resource for writing Access SQL statements

Tags: ms-access, query

I am looking for an online resource for writing Access SQL statements. I write queries using SQL because the UI puts limitations on what can be queried. I have been using [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) for reference, however MS-Access sometimes has slightly different syntax, so when I run the query I get an error. Then I end up wasting time trying to figure out what I did wrong only to find out that Access does it differently.

Comment: First, don't use the w3fools site for anything. It has a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 6):

Here is Microsoft's page about Access SQL syntax:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-sql-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-HA010256402.aspx

and here is a tutorial about Access SQL syntax for Access 2000.  A bit dated, but the concept is still there:

http://www.cwnresearch.com/resources/databases/access/tutorials/access2000/SQLQueries/SQLQueries.html

Answer (score 3):

[DevGuru](http://www.devguru.com/) has an old, but excellent [reference for JetSQL](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/jetsql/home.asp), the SQL dialect used by Microsoft Access.

Answer (score -2):

There's not really a good online "build my query for me" resource. It's rather the reason most of us goto school and study mathy concepts and learn how to do these things with lots of study and peer review. I realize this doesn't help you, but it helps to understand the resounding "NO" you're going to get.

Now you do realized Microsoft has a visual query editor right? Kind of click and drag sort of builder. I figure you do.

I suggest asking a specific question about a specific query and specifying that you don't understand the problem for more help in the future.

Comment: Too long and felt like it was appropriate as an answer.

Comment: I actually agree with this answer. In my fledgling years as a developer, I heavily used the QBE (Query By Example) grid until one day I clicked 'SQL View' and actually saw the SQL that matched the QBE I just designed. Just from styling the QBE, I learned MSAccess SQL TBE (Trial By Error). While SQL resources may be around, IMHO specifics about using it directly were lacking years ago. + 1 !!!